# Get TID of thread running on CPU

Tags: linux, files, linux-kernel

Is it possible to get the TID of the thread that is currently running on a logical core, such as logical core 0? This is easy to do in kernel space, but I am not sure how to get the thread information from userspace.

Answer (score 2):

With procps' `ps`, one can do this with the "PSR" column:

```
ps -Leo stat,psr,comm
```

Some tasks will likely be sleeping or otherwise be descheduled. You can filter and sort to only running tasks ordered by logical CPU like this:

```
ps r -Leo stat,psr,comm | sort -nk2
```

Since `ps`'s iteration of `/proc` may span quantums, you may see multiple tasks reported as running on the same CPU.